# Variable of polynomial equation

Tags: polynomials, euler-mascheroni-constant

The expression below is used in psychrometric calculations to find dew point temperature ($T$) as a function of it's saturated vapor pressure($A$).

I am trying to reverse the equation to find the saturated vapor pressure ($A$) if the dew point temperature ($T$) is known.

I am trying to determine the value of "A" in terms of $T, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, $ and $x_5$

***Knowns:***   **$T, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$**

***Unknowns:***  **$A$**

$T = x1 + (Ax_2) + (A^2x_3) + (A^3x_4) + (x_5 * ({e^A}^{0.1984}))$

The part that boggles my mind is at the end, I cannot figure out how to simplify the expression if the polynomial is inside the exponent.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think a closed form expression is possible.The only way might be some sort of a numerical approach

Comment: As already commented, no hope for a closed form expression. Newton method would be the simplest. The problem is the starting point. If you provide the values of the $x_i$'s and the range of $A$ you want to consider, I could try to work something.